# Cross product of operators

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, operator-theory

How to show that:

$ (-i\nabla-eA)\times(-i\nabla-eA) = (ie\nabla \times A) $

i and e are constants
A is a vector field
$\nabla$ = vector differential operator

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\curl}{curl}\DeclareMathOperator{\del}{del}$
This is terribly formatted. Did you mean $$(-i\del-eA) \times (-i \del - eA) = ie\del \times A = ie \curl (A)?$$

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: He means $(-i\nabla-eA)\times(-i\nabla-eA) = (ie\nabla \times A)$. Hint: apply on a test function.

Comment: Raskolnikov already gave you the answer. But I just want to add the comment that the identity you wrote down is also the definition for the [curvature form of a connection on a vector bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_%28vector_bundle%29#Curvature)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I suggested in my hint, apply the operator on a test function $f$. Then

$$(-i\nabla-eA)\times(-i\nabla-eA)f = (-i\nabla-eA)\times(-i\nabla f-e A f)$$

Working this out we get

$$(-i\nabla-eA)\times(-i\nabla f-e A f)= -\nabla \times \nabla f + ie A\times \nabla f +i e \nabla \times (A f) + e^2 A \times A f$$

The first and last term are zero. The third term can be expanded using [the last identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28mathematics%29#Identities) (or simply working it out in terms of partial derivatives). This will give the result.

$$(-i\nabla-eA)\times(-i\nabla-eA) = (ie\nabla \times A)$$

Comment: Is there a way to see the source (latex code) of answers ?

Comment: I don't know. But here's the code for the last line: (-i\nabla-eA)\times(-i\nabla-eA) = (ie\nabla \times A)

Comment: @kallemann: Right-click on any $\LaTeX$ entity you see; click on "Show Source", and you shall see the $\LaTeX$ code.

Comment: Thanks J.M.! Is this a feature of math.stackexchange only or is this generally implemented according to some standard?

Comment: @Ras: It's a [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) feature, actually. :)

Comment: @Raskolnikov - in general, when you write $(\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B})f=\mathbf{A}\times (\mathbf{B} f)$ - what's the justification for acting on $f$ with $\mathbf{B}$ first? The same thing happens in quantum mechanics when you act with operators on state vectors (in Hilbert space). Is it because $f$ (a state vector) is like a "scalar"?

Comment: @trfv : I think it is more a matter of convention. The convention could have been made differently and there would have been different bracketing in the working out of the results. [Take a look at this page about the del operator.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del) It gives you an idea of the conventions. Especially, in the precautions section.